# Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install'

Tags: pi-4

I'm new to Raspberry Pi, and I'm trying to download 0 a.d. but when I run

`sudo apt install 0ad`

I am met with

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 0ad : Depends: 0ad-data (>= 0.0.23.1) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: 0ad-data (<= 0.0.23.1-5) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: 0ad-data-common (>= 0.0.23.1) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: 0ad-data-common (<= 0.0.23.1-5) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: libboost-filesystem1.71.0 but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: libenet7 but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: libgloox18 (>= 1.0.24) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: libminiupnpc17 (>= 1.9.20140610) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: libnvtt2 but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: libwxbase3.0-0v5 (>= 3.0.5.1+dfsg) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: libwxgtk3.0-gtk3-0v5 (>= 3.0.5.1+dfsg) but it is not going to be installed
 steam-launcher : Depends: xterm but it is not going to be installed or
                           gnome-terminal but it is not going to be installed or
                           konsole but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: steam-libs-amd64 but it is not installable
                  Recommends: steam-libs-i386 but it is not installable
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I then run

`apt --fix-broken install`
and I get

```
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root?
```

I am stuck here and starting to get stressed out. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Did you *"do your homework"*... meaning did you search for a solution before posting here? Your question suggests that you **did not** do your homework. Please try that first - [here's a start - just for you](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=apt+--fix-broken+install+and+I+get+E%3A+Could+not+open+lock+file&t=newext&atb=v369-1&ia=web)!

Comment: You need to use `sudo` for all `apt` or `apt-get` or `dpkg` operations that install or configure or remove software packages.